# Disable JSP functionality on CF2021

Tags: coldfusion

We are using the same website to host CF and Confluence (confluence runs jsp) with a URL rewrite rule to redirect to a different port 8090 which works fine as long as the url does not have .jsp in it...

but if the url does have .jsp in it CF takes over and tries to process the page so we want to disable CF from taking over.

I read that you can disable JSP at least on CF 9 - https://www.3gpp2.org/cfdocs/htmldocs/Installing/WSf01dbd23413dda0e5753779b11fae614009-8000.html

by commenting out

```
<!-- <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>JspLicenseServlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping> -->
```

in  cf_root\WEB-INF\web.xml.  But I can't find JspLicenseServlet in cf_root\WEB-INF\web.xml on CF 2021.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I would recommend running Confluence on its own IIS site using a subdomain in order to avoid the conflict you're encountering. You should not have the CF connector assigned to every IIS site, just the one that is specifically running the CF application.

According to the [CF documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/installing/configuring-your-system.html),

> **Disabling JSP functionality (server configuration only)**
>
> ColdFusion Enterprise Edition provides support for JavaServer Pages (JSP) technology through the underlying J2EE application server on which it runs. Because JSP code runs outside the realm of the ColdFusion security framework and, therefore, is not subject to ColdFusion sandbox security, you do not typically deploy JSPs in a shared, hosted environment where more than one customer shares a single server.

> **DISABLE JSP FUNCTIONALITY**

1. Open `cf_root/cfusion/runtime/conf/web.xml` in a text editor.
2. Find the servlet-mapping entry for `JspLicenseServlet`.
3. Comment out this entry, as the following example shows:

```
    # I feel this is missing some code
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    -->
```

4. Save and close the file.
5. Restart ColdFusion.